# NAudio for multi threading: Buffers already queued on play error

Tags: .net, multithreading, exception, naudio

My application is running the audio play and we are playing the audio on multi thread. Some times the error is giving error:

> Buffers already queued on Play (Assertion Failed: Abort=Quit, Retry=Debug, Ignore=Continue)

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but you're likely calling Play() while already playing an audio stream.

Also, don't re-use the player, see http://naudio.codeplex.com/workitem/15916